# scanf of struct makes program crash

Tags: c, pointers, struct, crash

this is the code. the function "leggi" is supposed to read the value of c[i].a but when I type the first number in the console the program crashes.
It's probably a pointers issue but i can't figure it out

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct cane{
    int a;
}cane;

void leggi(cane *c[20]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        scanf("%d", &c[i]->a );
}

int main(){
    int i;
    cane c[20];

    leggi(&c);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%d",c[i].a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&c` is a pointer to `cane[20]`. `cane *c[20]` is an array of 20 pointers to `cane`.

Comment: With arrays in `C` the array name `c` is already a pointer so there's no need to pass `&c` to `leggi(...)`

Comment: GCC says: `error: passing argument 1 of ‘leggi’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]`
—— `leggi(&c);`

—— `note: expected ‘cane **’ {aka ‘struct cane **’} but argument is of type ‘cane (*)[20]’ {aka ‘struct cane (*)[20]’}`

Comment: right thanks! @cleblanc

Comment: @cleblanc `c` is *not* a pointer. But it does decay to a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass the wrong type to the function.

If you want to pass an array to a function the array name decays to a pointer to its first element, therefore the argument is only a pointer to the type:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct cane{
    int a;
}cane;

void leggi(cane *c){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        scanf("%d", &(c[i].a) );
}

int main(){
    int i;
    cane c[20];

    leggi(c);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%d",c[i].a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the parentheses in `&(c[i].a)`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler They are not necessary, but i thought it is maybe clearer to read.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `&c` is `cane (*)[20]` i.e. a pointer to an array. You've declared the argument of the function to be `cane *[20]` which is (as a function argument) a `cane**` which is a pointer to a pointer.

You may have intended to pass a pointer to an element of the array instead:

```
void leggi(cane *c)
    // ...
    scanf("%d", &c[i].a );

//
leggi(c);
```

Or possibly you really intended to pass a pointer to the array instead:

```
void leggi(cane (*c)[20])
    scanf("%d", &(*c)[i].a )

//
leggi(&c);
```